# Does a Facebook Offer have a permalink?

Tags: facebook

I just found out about Facebook Offers, which seem pretty interesting. I know how to create one, my question is, once created, does it have a permanent link? I want to link to this Facebook Offer from a link inside my blog.

Thanks
Themos

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Comment: This question could have easily been asked in an app-development context and would have been completely relevant. Furthermore, the linked FAQ question does not actually say anything that would exclude this question. I have to disagree that this question is "off-topic."

However, it does seem to be easily answered by Facebook's own help documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it creates a permanent link.

As an example, here's a [permanent link to a Facebook Offer](https://www.facebook.com/einsteinbros/posts/10150654432142417) by a bagel shop.

When you create an offer it does get a permanent serialized link that you can share outside of Facebook (hence the `Sharing` utility). According to this [Facebook documentation](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=404498446244125#How-do-I-stop-an-offer-I%27m-running?) you can `stop` an offer and the link will still be available/visible but no one can claim the offer.  You can `delete` the offer and the permanent link will most likely 404.

Resources:
For more information and a detailed look at Facebook Offers I found this [blog entry](http://www.marismith.com/facebook-launches-facebook-offers-for-businesses/) helpful.